# Fullcalendar event component typescript test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Started to use fullcalendar and I am trying to make a test to test my event component that gets rendered for an event. The problem I am running into is `EventContentArg`. I getting typescript errors that my event property is missing a bunch of things that are not really related for the test to render. How can I fix the following error:

```js
Type '{ id: string; start: Date; end: Date; title: string; backgroundColor: string; borderColor: string; editable: boolean; textColor: string; resourceId: string; extendedProps: { type: { id: number; name: string; }; status: { ...; }; displayProperties: { ...; }; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'EventApi': _context, _def, _instance, setProp, and 26 more.ts(2740)
main.d.ts(1289, 5): The expected type comes from property 'event' which is declared here on type 'EventContentArg'
```

Here is part of my component

```js
import { EventContentArg } from '@fullcalendar/react';

export const EventContent = (event: EventContentArg) => {
  const { backgroundColor, timeText, view } = event,
    { end, extendedProps, start, title } = event.event,
    { displayProperties } = extendedProps,
    slotDuration = view.getOption('slotDuration') as ISlotDuration,
    slotDurationNumber = Math.floor(slotDuration.milliseconds / 60000),
    appointmentLength = end!.getTime() - start!.getTime(),
    duration = Math.floor(appointmentLength / 60000);

  return (
    <div>My Component</div>
  )
}
```

Here is my test

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { EventContentArg } from '@fullcalendar/react';

import { EventContent } from '.';
import { events } from '../../actions/mockData';
import { prettyDate } from './EventContent.stories';

test('event renders with all expected data', () => {
  let event = events[2];
  let timeText = `${prettyDate(event.start)} - ${prettyDate(event.end)}`;

  let args: EventContentArg = {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(133,33,51)',
    event,
    timeText: timeText,
    view: {
      getOption: () => {
        return {
          milliseconds: 900000,
        };
      },
    },
  };

  render(<EventContent {...args} />);
});
```

Here is the events from the mockData

```js
export const events = [
  ...,
  {
    id: '3',
    start: new Date(thirdStart),
    end: new Date(thirdEnd),
    title: 'Hair Coloring', // This would be like the service name
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(133,33,51)', // Should be based on event status
    borderColor: '#d2d2d2', // For now should be same color as bg
    editable: false,
    textColor: '#2d2d2d',
    resourceId: '2',
    extendedProps: {
      type: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Appointment',
      },
      status: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Scheduled',
      },
      displayProperties: {
        attendeeDetails: 'with Kylo Ren',
        resourceDetails: 'Chair 2',
        eventIcons: [],
      },
    },
  },
  ...,
];
```

Comment: What is the props type for `EventContent`?  Maybe you want a deep partial of `EventContentArg`, but probably you want to enforce that `args` matches the expected props.  Import the props type or use the roundabout way `let args: React.ComponentProps<typeof EventContent>`

Comment: @LindaPaiste `export const EventContent = (event: EventContentArg) `

Comment: ok so this is a genuine problem because your component is saying that it must be called with complete `EventContentArg` props.  Maybe you need a deep partial there?  Or manually specify which properties are required and which are optional?

Comment: @LindaPaiste That type comes from FullCalendar. Maybe I am using the wrong prop in my component?

Comment: I am not familiar with this package at all.  I'll check out the docs.

Comment: Ok so you are basically doing [the same as they are doing](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/72136a72245bd0401670f546644d1fa2ae25f886/react-typescript/src/DemoApp.tsx#L122) in their Typescript demo.  Their `function renderEventContent` requires the whole `EventContentArg` even though they only use two properties.  But you see how it can make it hard to test when there are required props that aren't used.  `{timeText: string; event: {title: string;} }` would make their `renderEventContent` much more flexible.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Ah ok. That is what I was missing. I thought since FC had that function, that I needed to use the whole thing. That was my bad. This is now fixed, I believe